# Why did my SO reputation transfer to MSO?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Why did my reputation from Stack Overflow transfer to Stack Meta Overflow? Was this supposed to happen?

Are the reps linked together now, (If I loose reputation here will it affect me on SO)?

Why didn't my badges transfer too then?

Comment: You have no MSO rep. MSO now is a real child of SO and no longer a separate site with its own reputation. In fact, there is no reputation here.

Comment: @Bart Wait so you are saying if I get down voted in Meta, It won't affect my rep?

Comment: Indeed. No more nights spent crying in a corner wondering why oh why your brilliance is not recognized.

Comment: @Bart Yeeeeeeepie! I feel like a free unicorn!

Comment: You have accounts on other Stack Exchange sites that have always worked like this with the main site's rep carrying over to their meta. Why would you think that MSO would be different now that it's a proper site meta rather than the strange hybrid it was before?

Comment: Funny how this question is at `-6` now.  It doesn't even matter, @Arian!  Freeeeee as a unicorn...

Comment: Tempted to down vote in order to help prove the answer ;) But, no; I won't!

Comment: @ChrisF I've never knew that... I started with MSO, I assumed that all the others functions in the same way.

Comment: @Arian, this makes me think of this XKCD comic: https://xkcd.com/180/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Was this supposed to happen

Yes

> Are the reps linked together now

Yes

Meta StackOverflow where you can ask question related to StackOverflow feature-request/bugs etc. so this is meta site for the StackOverflow now. You can see on your meta stackoverflow there is no reputation tab there so here is no reputation now.

If you have any question that related to complete stackexchange network site then you can ask [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)